# Android programming: I cant get data to reload into arrayadapter

Tags: android, arrays, android-fragments, android-arrayadapter

I am still stuck with this issue, can anyone help. It seems that my problem is that I cant update the data list. I have tried every solution that I've searched for on google etc.. but half the time i'm not even sure that I'm doing the correct thing.

I've used the onResume() to call notifyDataSetChanged, it didn't work. I've tried putting a refresh method into the adapter which i then called in OnResume(). Again it didn't work. Some people suggest clearing the adpater (adapter.clear();) in onResume and then using the addAll() function to relist the data but nothing works.

There has to be a simple solution to this. I have literally been stuck on this for 2 days now. very frustrated.

Here's my Fragment code again...

```
enter code here

public class SavedAppFragment extends ListFragment {

private static final String TAG = "AppClicked"; //DEBUGGER

private ArrayList<App> mSavedApps;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

//Populate the ArrayList
   mSavedApps = SavedAppData.get(getActivity()).getApps();


  AppAdapter adapter = new AppAdapter(mSavedApps);
  setListAdapter(adapter);

}

//LIST ITEM CLICKED: /*Control what happens when list item is clicked: I.E. Load up a quiz while putting an EXTRA key containg the package name of the App to be launhced should the user get the question correct */ @Override public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position,long id) { //Return the crime for the list item that was clicked App c = ((AppAdapter) getListAdapter()).getItem(position); Log.d(TAG, "was clicked");

        //Start the Activity that will list the detail of the app
        Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), Quiz_Activity.class);
        String name = c.getPackage();
        i.putExtra("packagename", name);
        startActivity(i);
}

private class AppAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

    private ArrayList<App> mSavedApps;

    public AppAdapter(ArrayList<App> apps) {

        super(getActivity(), 0, apps);

    }




    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        //If we weren't given a view, inflate one
        if (null == convertView) {
            convertView = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.list_item_app, null);
            //((AppAdapter) getListAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        ((AppAdapter) getListAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
        //Configure the view for this crime
        App c = getItem(position);


            TextView nameTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.app_name);
            nameTextView.setText(c.getName());
            // nameTextView.setText(applicationInfo.loadLabel(packageManager));


            TextView packageTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.app_package);
            packageTextView.setText(c.getPackage());



            CheckBox appCheckBox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.app_checked);
            appCheckBox.setChecked(c.isChecked());


            //Return the view object to the ListView
            return convertView;


    }

}

}
```

THANKS!!!

Answer (score 1):

When you return to Activity B, the previous Activity B hasn't been destroyed. Thus, it skips the `onCreate`. Move all of the stuff you want to make sure happens every time into the `onResume`. I think you want to make your Adapter a class variable (I'll call it `mAdapter`) in `onCreate`, and add code that will get data from the list directly. If you need to do something, put a "refresh" function in the adapter. I'm assuming you have a custom Adapter, because I've never heard of `AppAdapter`. If you don't, then extend `AppAdapter` and add that functionality. Thus, your onCreate should look like this:

```
   mAdapter = new AppAdapter(mSavedApps);
   setListAdapter(mAdapter);
```

Your onRefresh could update the data contained in the adapter by some new update function, like so:

```
mAdapter.update(SavedAppData.get(getActivity()).getApps());
```

Comment: Thanks. Where should I call the "refresh" function from? I've spent many hours at this and tried everything. Would it be more sensible to kill the Activity B or how would I do that? Also, is  my code "AppAdapter adapter = new AppAdapter(mSavedApps);
       setListAdapter(adapter);" in onCreate not the same as your suggestion "mAdapter = new AppAdapter(mSavedApps);
   setListAdapter(mAdapter);"? thanks again

Comment: mAdapter.update() doesn't resolve anywhere other than in onCreate. Is that a valid method?

Comment: I'm sorry. Could you give me an example of that. I am really at the end of my tether with this. I have created a new function named "Refresher" and call it from OnResume(). It doesn;t do anything though and i dont know how to add the update method you mention to the custom adapter as you suggested. 

my "refresher" function:
`code`
   public void Refresher() {
        AppAdapter adapter = new AppAdapter(mSavedApps);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        mSavedApps = SavedAppData.get(getActivity()).getApps();
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }
`code`